# Xamarin - Deserialize empty Json

Tags: json, xamarin, json-deserialization

I have following code to deserialize a Json String.

```
var deserializedUrl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<galURL>(GalUrl);
```

Problem is, if the user entered a invalid code, the returned Json string is empty.. its simply `[]`.

The app crashes.. What would be a proper way to solve this?
I'd add a try/catch but maybe there is a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below code

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
        };
        try
        {
          var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<galURL>(GalUrl,settings);                    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
```